# ¿Porque al momento de refrescar me sale que "Referencia de objeto no establecida en una instancia de un objeto"?

Tags: c#, ajax, objeto, null

Estoy realizando una tabla con ajax, al igual que estoy implementando un var item in  ViewBag.userList, pero al momento de correr el programa me sale que hay  una referencia en var item in  ViewBag.userList que no esta establecida en una instancia de objeto.
¿Qué esta mal en mi código?

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 mt-1">
            @*@if (ViewBag.userList != null)*@
            @* { *@
            <div class="" id="tableConsultaAjax">
                <div class="table-responsive" id="freeStyle"></div>
                <table id="tableMainUno" class="table  table-bordered table-sm" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                    <thead style="background-color: @HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.GetString("AppMainColor").ToString(); color: @HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.GetString("AppTableTextColor").ToString()">
                        <tr>
                            <th rowspan="2" class="text-center">@Resource.IdOrder </th>
                            <th rowspan="2" class="text-center">@Resource.RequestDateDescription </th>
                            <th rowspan="2" class="text-center">@Resource.PriceDescription </th>
                            <th rowspan="2" class="text-center">@Resource.ScrapDescription </th>
                            <th rowspan="2" class="text-center">@Resource.QuantityDescription </th>
                            <th rowspan="2" class="text-center">@Resource.MeasurDescription</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id="bodyTableMainUno">
                        @foreach (var item in  ViewBag.userList)
                        {
                           
                        <tr role="row">
                            <td>@item.IdOrder</td>
                            <td>@item.RequestDateDescription </td>
                            <td>@item.PriceDescription</td>
                            <td>@item.ScrapDescription</td>
                            <td>@item.QuantityDescription</td>
                            <td>@item.MeasurDescription</td>

                            </tr>
                        }
                    </tbody>
                </table>

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que asegurarte que desde el `action`que haga uso de esa `view` siempre asigne la lista.

Esto no solo debe realizarse en un action marcado con `HttpGet` sino tambien en uno con `HttpPost` ya que entre las dos acciones no se mentiene el estado de los datos

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        //consultas los datos

        ViewBag.userList = lista;

        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        // realizas validaciones y grabas los datos

        ViewBag.userList = lista;

        return View();
    }
}
```

como veras en el post debes volver asignar el viewbag para volver a renderizar la view, sino lo haces entonces tendras ese mensaje que describes